# Problem saving data with a Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, save

Im using **Woo estimated shipping date** plugin to add a custom text (field) in my products pages.
The problem is:

Example: If I use this text in that custom field: "In stock" and then I save the changes, the plugin show "In stock" in the product page...**BUT** if I go back to edit anything else on the product page, the plugin restore the default sentence "Estimated Delivery Date" and if I save the changes without modifying that sentences once more, the "Estimated Delivery Date" shows in the product page instead the new sentence. Its something like an annoying loop, after save the changes always back the default text and If I don't look that field my custom text is gone.

Here's the Plugin code:

```
<?php 
/**
* No cheating please
*/
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) exit;

/**
* WCESD_Product_Settings Class
*/
class WCESD_Product_Settings {
/**
 * Hold the instance
 * 
 * @var string
 */
private static $instance;

use helperMethods;

/**
 * Constructor method
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct() {
    if ( ! $this->enabled() ) {
        return;
    }

    $this->init_hooks();
}

/**
 * Init all the hooks
 * 
 * @return void
 */
protected function init_hooks() {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_shipping', array( $this, 'wc_esd_add_estimated_shipping_date' ) );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', array( $this, 'wc_esd_save_shipping_date') );       
}

/**
 * Add wcesd form
 * 
 * @return void
 */
public function wc_esd_add_estimated_shipping_date() {
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array(
        'id'            => 'wc_esd_date_enable',
        'label'         => __( 'Habilitar fecha estimada entrega', 'wcesd' ),
        'description'   => __( 'Enable or Disable woocommerce estimated shipping date', 'wcesd' ),
        'desc_tip'      => true,
    ) );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => 'wc_esd_date',
        'label'         => __( 'Fecha estimada en días', 'wcesd' ),
        'description'   => __( 'Días del posible arribo del producto', 'wcesd' ),
        'desc_tip'      => true,
        'type'          => 'number',
        'placeholder'   => 5,
        'value'         => 5,
    ) );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => 'wc_esd_date_message',
        'label'         => __( 'Frase', 'wcesd' ),
        'description'   => __( 'Agregue su mensaje', 'wcesd' ),
        'desc_tip'      => true,
        'placeholder'   => 'Estimated Delivery Date',
        'value'         => 'Estimated Delivery Date',
    ) );

    do_action( 'wc_esd_add_estimated_shipping_date' );
}

/**
 * Save wcesd form data
 * 
 * @param  int $product_id
 * 
 * @return void
 */
public function wc_esd_save_shipping_date( $product_id ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() || get_post_type() !== 'product' ) {
        return;
    }

    $wc_esd_date_enable  = isset( $_POST['wc_esd_date_enable'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['wc_esd_date_enable'] ) : '';
    $wc_esd_date         = isset( $_POST['wc_esd_date'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['wc_esd_date'] ) : '';
    $wc_esd_date_message = isset( $_POST['wc_esd_date_message'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['wc_esd_date_message'] ) : '';

    update_post_meta( $product_id, 'wc_esd_date_enable', $wc_esd_date_enable );
    update_post_meta( $product_id, 'wc_esd_date', $wc_esd_date );
    update_post_meta( $product_id, 'wc_esd_date_message', $wc_esd_date_message );

    do_action( 'wc_esd_save_shipping_date', $product_id );
}

/**
 * Get instance
 * 
 * @return object
 */
public static function init() {
    if ( null === self::$instance ) {
        self::$instance = new self();
    }

    return self::$instance;
}

/**
 * Disable cloning this class
 * 
 * @return void
 */
private function __clone() {
    //
}

private function __wakeup() {
    //
}
}

WCESD_Product_Settings::init();
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the value field

```
woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
    'id'            => 'wc_esd_date_message',
    'label'         => __( 'Frase', 'wcesd' ),
    'description'   => __( 'Agregue su mensaje', 'wcesd' ),
    'desc_tip'      => true,
    'placeholder'   => 'Estimated Delivery Date',
    /*'value'         => 'Estimated Delivery Date',*/
) );
```

Then it should work.

Comment: Awesome, mate! Thank you so much! :)